# Where to kick a ball to achieve rolling during the whole motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

That's all the information I've got, so I don't really know what to do. But this is my idea: The equations of the motion are
$$ma=F_0\delta(t)-F_{friction}$$ and $$\frac{2mR^2}{5} \frac{d \alpha}{d t}=F_{friction}R+\delta(t)F_0 r,$$ where $R$ is the radius of the ball, $m$ is the mass of the ball and $r$ is the distance from the center of the ball to the hitting point. But I think I've done it wrong.

Comment: This process http://adaptivemap.ma.psu.edu/websites/statically_equivalent_systems/resolution_of_a_force/resolutionofaforce.html may give a hint...

Comment: Better to describe the situation first instead of jumping into equations which may or may not be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a motionless ball of radius $R$ resting on a horizontal plane with finite friction coefficient $\mu$. You kick the ball at a height $h$ above the ground along the horizontal direction and observe its motion. You want to find $h$ where it starts with pure rolling, instead of sliding.

This is the *axis of percussion problem*, and it is fairly simple to solve.

[image: ball]

What is important is the mass of the ball $m$, and the mass moment of inertia about the center of mass $I$.

The impulse $J$ from the kick might cause and reaction impulse $G$ from the ground, and the friction is low this reaction is limited in magnitude due to traction before the ball slips. So the goal here is to find $h$ such that $G=0$.

The equations of motion (horizontal and rotational) are:

$$ \begin{aligned}
  J - G & = m v \\
  J (h-R) + G R & = I \omega \\
\end{aligned} $$

and the pure rolling condition is $v = \omega R$

The solution to the above two equations is

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \omega &= \frac{h}{I+m R^2} J \\
  G & = J - \frac{h\,R\,m}{I+m R^2} J
\end{aligned} $$

To achieve the goal of $G=0$, solve the 2nd equation for $h$

$$ \boxed{ h = R + \frac{I}{m\,R} } $$

The resulting motion is thus

$$ \begin{aligned}
\omega &= \frac{J}{m\,R} & v & = \frac{J}{m}
\end{aligned} $$

NOTE: The *axis of precussion* defined by $h$ is **always** above the center of mass, and that makes sense since if it was near the center of mass the ball would try to translate (and slip).

References:

- The same math for a [related problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/250997/392) although inverted.
- An [even more detailed analysis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112563/392), of how to efficiently slide a bowling pin (the opposite problem).